# I'm trying to make something in a python gui where you type something into a input, click a button, and it should print what I've typed onto a list

Tags: python

so this is my code right now and I was looking to see if you could help me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 

ad = Tk()
ad.geometry("300x300+500+200")
ed = Entry(ad)
ed.pack()

ed.focus_set()

def callback():
    pass

button = Button(ad, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Pretty sure you should be make a label with it’s text as ed.get() or something

Comment: to format code use ``` instead of ''' - or select code and use Ctrl+K

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title

Comment: if you want to print text from `ed` then use  `print( ed.get() )` in `callback()`

Answer (score 1):

Frankly you should find it in many tutorials - `ed.get()`

You can use it to `print()` on screen or `.append()` to list.

---

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def callback():
    print( ed.get() )
    my_data.append( ed.get() )
    print(my_data)
    print('-----')
    
# --- main ---

my_data = []

root = tk.Tk()

ed = tk.Entry(root)
ed.pack()
ed.focus_set()

button = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=callback)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *

ad = Tk()
ad.geometry("300x300+500+200")
ed = Entry(ad)
ed.pack()

ed.focus_set()

list = Listbox (ad)
list.pack()

def callback():
    text = ed.get()
    list.insert(END,text)

         

button = Button(ad, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I just added the print format in the callback function. That's it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 

ad = Tk()
ad.geometry("300x300+500+200")
ed = Entry(ad)
ed.pack()

ed.focus_set()

def callback():
    print(ed.get())

button = Button(ad, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```